# Is it possible to write join with a boolean evaluation?

Tags: linq

I want to write

```
CompareInfo myCompIntl = CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo( "es-ES" );
var SharedYomi = from ObjA in ClassListA
                 join ObjB in ClassListB
                 where CompareInfo.Compare(ObjA.Name, ObjB.Name) == 0
                 select new {stringA = stringA, string = string};
```

Linq forces me to write join with equals. I can not pass in a Boolean evaluation. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write that using the LINQ lambda query syntax. The `join` keyword requires you to specify exactly two properties that are compared using the `equals` keyword, because this maps to the first overload of [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) that uses the default comparer to compare keys.

However, there is an overload of [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549267.aspx) that accepts an `IEqualityComparer` that will probably work for you, you just need to use method query syntax.

Since you sound like you're not familiar with the method syntax, here's a good starting article from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx

But, basically, the syntax you think of as "LINQ" is just one way to refer to the LINQ extensions, and is really just syntactic sugar around the `IEnumerable` extension methods that implement LINQ. So, for example, the query:

```
from x in y where x.IsActive orderby x.Name select x
```

it basically identical to

```
y.Where(x => x.IsActive).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x);
```

For the most part, each query clause maps to a particular overload of a particular `IEnumerable` method, but those methods have a number of other overloads that take different numbers and types of parameters.

The `Join` methods are a bit complex, because they take two sequences as input and let you combine individual elements of them using expressions, but the idea is exactly the same. A typical join would look like this:

```
from x in y
join a in b on x.Id equals a.ParentId
select new { x.Id, x.Name, a.Date }
```

becomes

```
y.Join(
  b, 
  x => x.Id, 
  a => a.ParentId, 
  (x, a) => new { x.Id, x.Name, a.Date });
```

This will join `a.ParentId` and `x.Id` using the default comparison for their data type (int, string, whatever). The compiler directly translates the query syntax into method syntax, so the two behave exactly the same. (Nitpicking my own answer: Technically, the methods are on the `Enumerable` class, so you are really calling `Enumerable.Join`. But as they were implemented as extension methods, you can call them either way and the compiler will figure it out.)

In your case, what you need is to pass in a different comparison method, so you can call `string.Compare` with the explicit encoding. The other overload of `Join` lets you supply an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` to use instead of the default. This will require you to implement `IEqualityComparer<string>` in a separate class, since there's no easy way to create an anonymous interface implementation (perhaps the only feature I miss from Java). For your example, you want something like this:

```
public class ComparerWithEncoding : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
  private CompareInfo compareInfo
  public ComparerWithEncoding ( string encoding )
  {
    this.compareInfo = CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo(encoding);
  }

  public bool Equals ( string a, string b )
  {
    return CompareInfo.Compare(a, b) == 0
  }

  public int GetHashCode(string a)
  {
    return a.GetHashCode();
  }
}

classListA.Join(
  ClassListB,
  ObjA => ObjA.Name,
  ObjB => ObjB.Name,
  (ObjA, ObjB) => new { stringA = ObjA.Foo, stringB = ObjB.Bar },
  new ComparerWithEncoding("es-ES"));
```

Comment: What is the syntax of that overloaded Join?

Comment: I don't know how to refer it. It's different from the "from x in y" sementics

Comment: How do you refer the two different types of syntax in linq?
from x in y join z select x and y.join(z, x=>x)?

Comment: I added an edit to the answer to include a sample, but its pending review so I'll post it in comments as well. Something like: `var result = ClassListA.Join(ClassListB, x => x, x => x, (a, b) => new { ValueA = a, ValueB = b }, EqualityComparer<int>.Default);`